# ASP.Net Entity Framework many to many update not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can add a new agency with the sectors chosen but when I got to modify an existing agency to either add or remove existing sectors, the changes aren't saved for the relationship.

My POST method

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Agency agency, string[] selectedOptions)
{
        if (agency.id == 0)
        {
            agency.id = _db.Agencies.Count() + 1;

            UpdateAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency);
            _db.Agencies.Add(agency);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new {success = true, message = "Saved successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        agency.lastupdated = DateTime.Now;
        UpdateAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency);
        _db.Entry(agency).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new {success = true, message = "Updated successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My update sectors method

```
private void UpdateAgencySectors(string[] selectedOptions, Agency agency)
{
        if (selectedOptions == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selectedOptionsHs = new HashSet<string>(selectedOptions);
        var agencySectors = new HashSet<int>(agency.Sectors.Select(b => b.id));

        foreach (var sector in _db.Sectors)
        {
            if (selectedOptionsHs.Contains(sector.id.ToString()))
            {
                if (!agencySectors.Contains(sector.id))
                {
                   agency.Sectors.Add(sector);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (agencySectors.Contains(sector.id))
                {
                    agency.Sectors.Remove(sector);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The `selectedOptions` array gets the id(s) of the chosen sector(s) from a listbox. When I debug, I can see that they are being detected, just that they are not saving to the updated state.

My agency model has the sectors as a collection. Here's a part of it.

```
public partial class Agency
{
    public Agency()
    {
        this.Sectors = new HashSet<Sector>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by clearing the join database of any relationship at the beginning of the post and the redoing the relationships. Code is;

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Agency agency, string[] selectedOptions)
    {
        var dbTable = "AgencySector";

        if (agency.id == 0)
        {
            agency.created = DateTime.Now;
            agency.createdby = 1;
            agency.createdbytype = "A";
            agency.lastupdated = DateTime.Now;
            agency.lastupdatedby = 1;
            agency.lastupdatedbytype = "A";
            agency.deleted = false;

            UpdateAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency, dbTable);
            _db.Agencies.Add(agency);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new {success = true, message = "Saved successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        _db.Agencies.Attach(agency); //attaches chosen agency

        UpdateAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency, dbTable);
        _db.Entry(agency).CurrentValues.SetValues(typeof(AgencySectorViewModel));
        //adds relationship found in UpdateAgencySectors

        agency.lastupdated = DateTime.Now; //updates modified time
        _db.Entry(agency).State = EntityState.Modified;         
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new {success = true, message = "Updated successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private void UpdateAgencySectors(string[] selectedOptions, Agency agency, string dbTable)
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Delete"].ConnectionString);           
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from " + dbTable  +
                                        " where " + dbTable + " = " + agency.id, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (selectedOptions == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selectedOptionsHs = new HashSet<string>(selectedOptions);
        var agencySectors = new HashSet<int>
            (agency.Sectors.Select(b => b.id));

        foreach (var sector in _db.Sectors)
        {
            if (!selectedOptionsHs.Contains(sector.id.ToString())) continue;
            if (!agencySectors.Contains(sector.id))
            {
                agency.Sectors.Add(sector);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see here that I'm passing in the name of the table I want to clear of a relationship

```
var dbTable = "AgencySector";
```

and my query for clearing the relationship is;

```
var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Delete"].ConnectionString);           
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from " + dbTable  +
                                    " where " + dbTable + ".agencyid = " + agency.id, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I've made sure to not hard code as much as I can so far to make it reusable for other tables. It probably can be improved but for now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to fix it for you but it might be worth a shot. I would try just adding the items to the db instead of trying to detect the changes through the state.

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Agency agency, string[] selectedOptions)
{
    if (agency.id == 0)
    {
        agency.id = _db.Agencies.Count() + 1;

        UpdateAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency);
        _db.Agencies.Add(agency);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new {success = true, message = "Saved successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    agency.lastupdated = DateTime.Now;
    _db.Sectors.AddRange(GetAgencySectors(selectedOptions, agency));
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new {success = true, message = "Updated successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private ICollection<Sector> UpdateAgencySectors(string[] selectedOptions, Agency agency)
{
    List<Sector> sectors = new List<Sector>();

    if (selectedOptions == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var selectedOptionsHs = new HashSet<string>(selectedOptions);
    var agencySectors = new HashSet<int>(agency.Sectors.Select(b => b.id));
    foreach (var sector in _db.Sectors)
    {
        if (selectedOptionsHs.Contains(sector.id.ToString()))
        {
            if (!agencySectors.Contains(sector.id))
            {
               sectors.Add(sector);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (agencySectors.Contains(sector.id))
            {
                sectors.Remove(sector);
            }
        }
    }
    return sectors;
}
```

EDIT: Just realized this would not return items that would need to be deleted from the db. I would try the code out to see if it works then try to get it to delete after.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, sorry it's taken me so long to respond back. Yes, it does work for adding new sectors and as you said, it doesn't delete. It's a workaround, but I'm still wondering why my original doesn't work. The debugger is showing all the correct info, the database just isn't being edited.

Comment: @KieranDee looks like you figured out a solution, glad you were able to figure something out. My guess as to why your first approach doesn't work is EF for some reason is not picking up the changes. I know there are ways to force the changes such as when you used `_db.Entry(agency).State = EntityState.Modified;` but there may be more to it for properties that go to a child entity.